# IOS Adding a TabBar Controller to a view

Tags: ios, tabs, salesforce

My IOS app has a login sequence that cannot be modified, once the sequence is complete I do the following in the app delegate

```
- (UIViewController*)newRootViewController {
        NViewController *nView = [[NViewController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"NViewController"
                                    bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nView];
    [nView release];
    return navVC;
  }
```

Once in nView is it possible to add a tab bar controller or how can I replace nView with a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UITabBarController then add your NViewController and other controllers to the tab bar.

```
NViewController *nView = [[NViewController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"NViewController"
                          bundle:nil];

//Create my tab bar
UITabBarController* myTabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

//Add my tabs
NSArray* tabs = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nView, nil];
[myTabController setViewControllers:tabs];
```

Comment: You can set myTabController as the root controller